# Configuration manipulation over all Visual Studio projects

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, solution

some one know how can I manipulate on some configuration over all projects in solution?
For example, I create new configuration "Releas64" that means: "No debug, 64 bit, all files goes to c:\binaries", but I need to go over all 30 projects in our solution for to set those settings for every project.

Is there some tool?
Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in Visual Studio: Build -> Configuration Manager and set Active Solution Configuration to your "Releas64".

Comment: Thank you for replay, but my question was how to set parameters like target and platform for all project and not how to select configuration